I have an issue with a circular default in TypeScript that I don't know how to solve
I want to define types the following way:
export type SequenceNode<
  T extends ComponentSequenceNode = ComponentSequenceNode,
  U extends ContainerSequenceNode = ContainerSequenceNode
> = T | U;

export interface ComponentSequenceNode<T extends SequenceNode = SequenceNode> {
  id: string;
  node: "sequence";
  sequence: "component";
  next: T[];
}

export interface ContainerSequenceNode<T extends SequenceNode = SequenceNode> {
  id: string;
  node: "sequence";
  sequence: "container";
  next: T[];
  into: T[];
}

However, I get a message saying that I have a circular default with these types.
I want to define the types using generics and using this structure but I don't know how to achieve it.

I would really try to avoid such circular defaults if I were you; this is one of the places where any would be much better than trying to represent this, since circularities can bite you when you don't expect them. Still, if I were forced to try to do this, I would define new Base interfaces which defers some of the recursion, as shown in this playground link. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing

The problem is, that this type parameter definition is recursive, the default type of that SequenceNode could be something like
SequenceNode<SequenceNode<SequenceNode<..., ...>, SequenceNode<..., ...>>, SequenceNode<SequenceNode<..., ...>, SequenceNode<..., ...>>>

and the compiler will try to evaluate that never ending chain.
So instead, as a default, use SequenceNode<any, any> so the chain "stops" there:
export type SequenceNode<
  T extends ComponentSequenceNode = ComponentSequenceNode,
  U extends ContainerSequenceNode = ContainerSequenceNode
> = T | U;

export interface ComponentSequenceNode<T extends SequenceNode = SequenceNode<any, any>> {
  id: string;
  node: "sequence";
  sequence: "component";
  next: T[];
}

export interface ContainerSequenceNode<T extends SequenceNode = SequenceNode<any, any>> {
  id: string;
  node: "sequence";
  sequence: "container";
  next: T[];
  into: T[];
}

Your code still works the same, any SequenceNode<Something, SomethingElse> satisfies the T extends SequenceNode type, but by default it is typed more specific.
Here's a TS-Playground link: https://tsplay.dev/wXL3Jw

I can't use any. It is a bad practice

Without any caveats, "any is a bad practice" is either false or misleading.
